# Update: subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql

I am having a problem, and I can't figure out how to fix this query.  I have a temp table, one of the columns should contain a calculated value of another column divided by a sum of groups of that column.  I don't know how to write this so that I avoid the error.

```
Declare @Temp Table
(           
    ZipCode char(5) Not Null,
    StateFacilityId varchar (50) Not Null,
    Cnt int Not Null,
    MarketShare float,
    Row int Not Null,
    Primary Key Clustered (ZipCode, StateFacilityId)
);


Insert Into @Temp (ZipCode, StateFacilityId, Cnt, Row)
Select d.ZipCode, d.StateFacilityId, Cnt = COUNT(*), Row = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ZipCode ORDER BY Count(*) DESC)
From [MarketShareIQData].[dbo].[tblServicesDetail] d    
Group By d.ZipCode, d.StateFacilityId
;


Update @Temp
Set MarketShare =(h.Cnt/(
                Select SUM(h.Cnt)
                From @Temp h
                Group By ZipCode
                ))
From @Temp h
```

Answer (score 1):

A `group by` would return one row per group.  I'm guessing you're looking for the single group with matching zipcode.  You could do that like:

```
update h
set     MarketShare = h.Cnt /
        (
        select  sum(h2.Cnt)
        from    @Temp h2
        where   h2.ZipCode = h.ZipCode
        )
from    @Temp h
```

Comment: I think I want group,  I want the denominator to be the sum of counts of all rows with the same zip code.